# License Management Application (LMA) in scratch org

Tags: scratch-org, lma, lmo

We would like to do some sort of exploration of License Management Application, i.e. play with it, look at new objects added to SF schema, maybe write some triggers etc.

Is it possible to spin up a scratch org with LMA installed there, e.g. by specifying some magical keys in json config?

Can we at least install LMA manually into scratch org after having it created, e.g. by typing package installation url manually? If so, what is package installation url for LMA?

Is there anyway not do go via SF support case to get LMA package url every time? We would like to be able to re-create scratch org with LMA in case if we messed up with some changes etc. This is solely for investigation purposes - when we finalize an approach we will create standalone org (LMO) and log support case properly.

Answer (score 6):

As long as you have the package ID, you can:

```
sfdx force:package:install --package 04t... --targetusername scratchOrgAlias
```

If you don't have the package ID, you can't use this command.

You can get package IDs via:

```
sfdx force:package:installed:list -u prodOrgAlias
```